# how to match content except and, or, ||, && in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

for example like this

```
$str = "1 < 4 and 8 > 2 or 4 * 3 or $m =~ /^\d+&\$/";
```

I would like to capture

- `1 < 4`
- `8 > 2`
- `4 * 3`
- `$m =~ /^d+&\$/`

however, `$str =~ /\s+(?<operators>and|or|&&|\|\|){1,}\s+/;` doesn't work, any help to modify

Comment: is it ok? \B(and|or|&&|\|\||^)(.*?)\B(and|or|&&|\|\||$)

Comment: regex /^d+&\$/ cannot be captured

Comment: The `and` and `or` have meaning in your example. Are you saying you want to discard the meaning of the logical and / or? Have you considered a parser?

Comment: No idea, what does it means. Can you show with other example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set $str to that, you should use single quotes (or escape all the meta characters).

```
my $str = '1 < 4 and 8 > 2 or 4 * 3 or $m =~ /^\d+&\$/';
my @capture = split  /\s+(?:and|or|&&|\|\|)\s+/, $str;
```

Comment: regex /^d+&\$/ cannot be captured

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: if a string contains regex and variables like having $m, /^\d+$/, it doesn't work. When matched, $m would disappear, print nothing like =~ /^\d+$/

Comment: $m disappears because you are using double quotes, so it tries to interpolate the variable $m into your string (and also doesn't do what you want with the backslashes).  Once $str is set to what you want it to be, the match has no problem.